# Using python pick a random element from a list with replacement

Tags: python, select, random

I have a list of 40 elements. I am trying to estimate how many times I need to sample this list in order to reproduce all elements in that list. However, it is important that I replace the picked element. I.e. it is possible that I will pick the same element 20 times. So far I have the following

```
import random
l = range(0,40)

seen=[]
x=0
while len(seen)<len(l):
    r = random.choice(l)
    if r not in seen:
        seen.append(r)
        x=x+1
print x
```

However, this always returns that it took 40 times to accomplish what I want. However, this is because a single element is never selected twice. 
Eventually I would run this function 1000 times to get a feel for how often I would have to sample.
as always, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need just adjust the indentation of `x=x+1`. Because right now you just increment if the value was not seen before.

If you will do that more often with a lot of items may use a `set` as your `seen` variable because access items is [faster in avarage](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity).

```
l = range(0, 40)
seen = set()
x = 0
while len(seen) < len(l):
    r = random.choice(l)
    if r not in seen:
        seen.add(r)
    x = x + 1
print x
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a similar method to do it. Initialize a `set`, which by definition may only contain unique elements (no duplicates). Then keep using `random.choice()` to choose an element from your list. You can compare your set to the original list, and until they are the same size, you don't have every element. Keep a counter to see how many random choices it takes.

```
import random

def sampleValues(l):
    counter = 0
    values = set()
    while len(values) < len(l):
        values.add(random.choice(l))
        counter += 1
    return counter

>>> l = list(range(40))
```

This number will vary, you could Monte Carlo to get some stats

```
>>> sampleValues(l)
180
>>> sampleValues(l)
334
>>> sampleValues(l)
179
```